# enable lacp mode active on isr 2951

Tags: networking, cisco, router, switch, vlan

Any idea if ISR 2951 support LACP ... i don't see any cli command to enable it.
My router IOS version is 15.2(4)M7. Can you help please.
below is my config:

```
interface Port-channel1.1
 description DEVICES$FW_INSIDE$$ETH-LAN$
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip flow ingress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in max-reassemblies 1024
 zone-member security in-zone
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 ip policy route-map PBR
!
interface Port-channel1.2
 description AFULL$FW_INSIDE$$ETH-LAN$
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 1.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip flow ingress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in max-reassemblies 1024
 zone-member security in-zone
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1300
 ip policy route-map PBR
```

HP Switch 1910:

```
interface Bridge-Aggregation1
 port link-type hybrid
 port hybrid vlan 1 to 4 tagged
 link-aggregation mode dynamic
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 port link-type hybrid
 port hybrid vlan 1 to 4 tagged
 poe enable
 stp edged-port enable
 port link-aggregation group 1
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 port link-type hybrid
 port hybrid vlan 1 to 4 tagged
 poe enable
 stp edged-port enable
 port link-aggregation group 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably want to include the configuration from the physical interfaces that are part of the etherchannel on the Cisco side.

Second, unfortunately you will not have the option of dynamic etherchannel with LACP, the ISR routers only support static etherchannel as you have apparently already configured.

Cisco documents the limitation here for the x8xx series ISR's here: http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/routers/3800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/prod_white_paper0900aecd806f698a.pdf

The config guide for 15M/T releases also doesn't indicate `mode active` as an option: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/interface/configuration/15-mt/ir-15-mt-book/ir-cfg-fec.html#GUID-4261FBD0-9D0A-4F8A-B30C-2035F120624A